# How to add a relationship properties column in a xlsx file

Tags: azure, properties, relationship, xlsx, azure-digital-twins

I am trying to create a digital twins by creating and uploading the xlsx file in Azure digital twin.

I am able to create a digital twin using the sample xlsx file shared on GitHub repository of ADT as shown in below snapshot:
[Sample xlsx file without the relationship properties column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aYwO.png)

In above image the twin properties are added by column 'init data'. But in my case the relationship also have their own properties associated with them.

So how can I include the relationship properties in the xlsx ?

What will be the name of the column for the relationship properties needed to be specified in xlsx ?

It will be helpful if you can share a xlsx having the multiple nodes and relationship where the relationship properties added in them.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the Azure Digital Twins explorer doesn't support uploading relationships with properties through Excel or JSON files. The [Excel plugin](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/digital-twins-explorer/blob/main/client/src/services/plugins/ExcelImportPlugin.js) currently only looks at the columns that are defined in the file. This means that if you absolutely must use an Excel file to import your twin, you would need to build this functionality yourself.

There is also an [open issue](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/digital-twins-explorer/issues/179) that describes relationship properties not being shown in ADT Explorer, so there doesn't seem to be support for it. You could use the API to create these relationships.

Comment: Thanks @Matthijs van der Veer for the response. It was helpful for me.

Comment: No problem, you can also always shoot the team a feature request. If this answer helped you, consider marking it as the accepted answer.